# Как правильно делать вложенное меню в Jinja2 Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Приветствую.

Следующая ситуация:

- Нужно построить меню, состоящее из 3-х пунктов (Men,Woman,Junior).
- В каждом из этих пунктов меню нужно сделать по 2 подпункта (категории) (Accessories, Shoes).
- В каждый подпункт нужно выбрать из таблицы те подкатегории, которые соответствуют данным категориям (если Shoes, то, к примеру, Nike Air Max, если Acessories, то, скажем, Hat Kangol).

В шаблоне Jinja это делается посредством нескольких циклов:

```
{% set query = Products.query %}
{% set genders = query.filter(Products.gender !=0).group_by(Products.gender) %}
    {% for li in genders %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url_for('shop.shop_grid', gender=li.gender) }}">{{li.gender}}</a>
                <!-- DRODOWN-MEGA-MENU START -->
                <div class="drodown-mega-menu">

                {% set categories = query.filter(Products.category != 0, Products.category != 'Clothing').group_by(Products.category).all() %}
                    {% for item in categories %}
                        <div class="left-mega col-xs-6">
                        <div class="mega-menu-list">

                        <a class="mega-menu-title" href="{{ url_for('shop.shop_grid', gender=li.gender) }}">{{item.category}}</a>
                            <ul>
                            {% set subcategory = Products.query.filter(Products.gender == li.gender, Products.category == item.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory) %}
                            {% for category in subcategory%}
                            <li><a href="{{ url_for('shop.shop_grid', gender=li.gender) }}">{{category.subcategory}}</a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
```

Но, как мы все понимаем, категорически неправильно делать выборку из шаблона, к тому же, Jinja регулярно кидает ошибку:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'Products' is undefined

Хотя меню отрисовывается так, как нужно.

Как правильно поступить в этой ситуации?
Генерить HTML внутри контроллера, и отдавать его рендерить в шаблон? 
В самом контроллере делать цикл, и передавать кучу переменных?

Почему бы не сделать пункты и подпункты руками, а в шаблон передавать только подкатегории ? Потому что количество подпунктов может измениться, а лезть в шаблон и править это там, кажется не правильным.

Вот те же циклы, но уже в controllers.py:

```
q = Products.query
genders = q.filter(Products.gender !=0).group_by(Products.gender)
categories = q.filter(Products.category != 0, Products.category != 'Clothing').group_by(Products.category).all()

for gender in genders:
    print(gender.gender)
    for category in categories:
        print(category.category)
        subcategories = q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory)
        for subcategory in subcategories:
            subcategory.subcategory
            print(subcategory.subcategory)
```

Вот то, что получается на выходе:

```
Junior
Accessories
Shoes
Men
Accessories
Hats
bags
socks
Shoes
Asics
Jordan Brand
New Balance
Nike
Puma
Reebok Classic
Saucony
adidas
Women
Accessories
backpacks
Shoes
Converse
Nike
Reebok Classic
adidas
```

Предполагаю, что лучшее что можно сделать - это передать всё это дело в формате JSON, только вот опыта работы с ним у меня почти нет.

```
q = Products.query
genders = q.filter(Products.gender !=0).group_by(Products.gender)
categories = q.filter(Products.category != 0, Products.category != 'Clothing').group_by(Products.category).all()



gen = {gender.gender: {category.category: {subcategory.subcategory for subcategory in q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory) } for category in categories} for gender in genders}

print(gen)
```

При помощи такой длинной строчки кода, получается практически то, что нужно:

```
{'Junior': {'Accessories': set(), 'Shoes': set()}, 'Women': {'Accessories': {'backpacks'}, 'Shoes': {'Reebok Classic', 'adidas', 'Nike', 'Converse'}}, 'Men': {'Accessories': {'socks', 'Hats', 'bags'}, 'Shoes': {'Saucony', 'Asics', 'Reebok Classic', 'Nike', 'Puma', 'adidas', 'New Balance', 'Jordan Brand'}}}
```

Однако, при попытке сделать `json.dumps` ругается

```
set() is not JSON serializable
```

И формат данных портится, из-за этих set().

Comment: Вот, нашёл интересную штуковину. Возможно поможет решить задачу. 
https://github.com/aromanovich/jinja2schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря ответу на вопрос от @insolor на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572477/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-set-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-dict) вопрос, решить удалось таким образом:

1. Как и было изначально в самом вопросе, выборку делаем в контроллере:

   `q = Products.query
   genders = q.filter(Products.gender !=0).group_by(Products.gender)
   categories = q.filter(Products.category != 0, Products.category != 'Clothing').group_by(Products.category).all()`
2. Затем из полученных данных генерируем словарь:

   `gen = {
       gender.gender: {
           category.category: {
               subcategory.subcategory for subcategory in q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory)
           } for category in categories
       } for gender in genders
   }`

   Кстати, всё это дело происходит в `@context_processor`, по этому передаём так: `return dict(gen=gen)`
3. Ну и наконец сама генерация меню в Jinja (в моём случае, это header.html)

   ```
   {% for gender in gen %}
   <li>
       <a href="{{ url_for('shop.shop_grid', gender=gender) }}">{{gender}}</a>
           <!-- DRODOWN-MEGA-MENU START -->
           <div class="drodown-mega-menu">

               {% for category in gen[gender] %}
                   <div class="left-mega col-xs-6">
                   <div class="mega-menu-list">

                   <a class="mega-menu-title" href="{{ url_for('shop.shop_grid', gender=gender) }}">{{category}}</a>
                       <ul>
                       {% for subcategory in gen[gender][category] %}
                       <li><a href="{{ url_for('shop.shop_grid', gender=gender) }}">{{subcategory}}</a></li>
                               {% endfor %}
                               </ul>
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               {% endfor %}
                               {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать то же самое для меню такого сайта? https://github.com/Muriam/python/tree/master/simple/Flask_projects/proj

Comment: @Muriam может быть Вам поможет это:

https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-megamenu.html
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/