# Как обработать set() при генерации dict

Tags: python

Есть вот такой вот словарь:

```
{'Junior': {'Shoes': set(), 'Accessories': set()}, 'Men': {'Shoes': {'New Balance', 'Asics', 'adidas', 'Nike', 'Saucony', 'Jordan Brand', 'Puma', 'Reebok Classic'}, 'Accessories': {'socks', 'Hats', 'bags'}}, 'Women': {'Shoes': {'Converse', 'Reebok Classic', 'adidas', 'Nike'}, 'Accessories': {'backpacks'}}}
```

Который генерируется вот таким вот генератором словарей:

```
   q = Products.query
    genders = q.filter(Products.gender !=0).group_by(Products.gender)
    categories = q.filter(Products.category != 0, Products.category != 'Clothing').group_by(Products.category).all()

    gen = {gender.gender: {category.category: {subcategory.subcategory for subcategory in q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory)} for category in categories} for gender in genders}
```

Не уверен, что генератор написан правильно, однако он работает почти так как надо.

Пробовал использовать `#gen = defaultdict(lambda:None,gen)`
Но потом понял, что работает это по другому принципу.

Дело в том, что в БД действительно нету элементов удовлетворяющих условию выборки(фильтра), по этому и такая картина `{'Junior': {'Shoes': set(), 'Accessories': set()}`

Такой словарь нельзя ни распарсить, ни привести к JSON, опять таки, по причине `set()`

**Задача в том, чтобы вместо set() записать None или False**

Comment: Можно либо при генерации, либо после нее привести сеты к спискам, тогда нормально преобразуется в json.

Comment: @insolor, не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно либо при генерации, либо после нее привести `set`'ы к спискам, тогда нормально преобразуется в json.

1 вариант - генерировать сразу списки, если повторений в исходных последовательностях нет. Просто меняем фигурные скобки в одном из генераторов на квадратные:

```
gen = {
    gender.gender: {
        category.category: [
            subcategory.subcategory for subcategory in q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory)
        ] for category in categories
    } for gender in genders
}
```

2 вариант - если возможны повторения подкатегорий, то просто оборачиваем генератор `set`'а в `list(...)`:

```
gen = {
    gender.gender: {
        category.category: list({
            subcategory.subcategory for subcategory in q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory)
        }) for category in categories
    } for gender in genders
}
```

3 вариант - приводить последовательности подкатегорий к спискам уже после генерации, но мне лень это реализовывать)

Результат будет примерно таким:

```
{'Junior': {'Shoes': [], 'Accessories': []}, 'Men': {'Shoes': ['New Balance', 'Asics', 'adidas', 'Nike', 'Saucony', 'Jordan Brand', 'Puma', 'Reebok Classic'], 'Accessories': ['socks', 'Hats', 'bags']}, 'Women': {'Shoes': ['Converse', 'Reebok Classic', 'adidas', 'Nike'], 'Accessories': ['backpacks']}}
```

что отлично сериализуется в json:

```
>>> json.dumps(s)
'{"Women": {"Shoes": ["Converse", "Reebok Classic", "adidas", "Nike"], "Accessories": ["backpacks"]}, "Junior": {"Shoes": [], "Accessories": []}, "Men": {"Shoes": ["New Balance", "Asics", "adidas", "Nike", "Saucony", "Jordan Brand", "Puma", "Reebok Classic"], "Accessories": ["socks", "Hats", "bags"]}}'
```

**Обновление.** На случай, если понадобится все-таки вставлять `None` вместо пустых `set`'ов, можно воспользоваться тем свойством, что пустой `set` в логических выражениях эквивалентен `False`, а если левый аргумент оператора `or` ложный, то вернется правый аргумент, т.е. `set() or None` равно `None`:

```
gen = {
    gender.gender: {
        category.category: {
            subcategory.subcategory for subcategory in q.filter(Products.gender == gender.gender, Products.category == category.category, Products.subcategory != 0).group_by(Products.subcategory)
        } or None for category in categories
    } for gender in genders
}
```

Comment: Большое, Вам, человеческое спасибо!

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik: реализация варианта 3: передайте `default` параметр `json.dumps(gen, default=lambda obj: list(obj) if isinstance(obj, set) else "raise TypeError")` В более общем случае [можно рекурсивно обходить структуру и/или использовать generic функции](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081150/4279)